# How to understand fftw benchmark?

Tags: fftw, flops

I read benchmark of fftw that is done by using many kinds of CPUs.
But, the unit of the measurement is MFLOPS, varying vector dimension from small to large.
I want to know the microseconds or milliseconds to perform a single inverse or regular fft.

How can I convert MFLOPS to seconds?

Answer (score 0):

As described on FFTW's [Benchmark Methodology](http://www.fftw.org/speed/method.html) page:

> To report FFT performance, we plot the "mflops" of each FFT, which is a scaled version of the speed, defined by:
>
> mflops = 5 N log2(N) / (time for one FFT in microseconds) for complex transforms, and
>    mflops = 2.5 N log2(N) / (time for one FFT in microseconds) for real transforms

For example, if we look at the [raw data file for the "1.06 GHz PowerPC 7447A, MacOSX" case](ftp://ftp.fftw.org/pub/fftw/numbers/ibook-macosx.tar.gz), the first entry is

```
arprec dcif 4 27.09 1.4765625e-06 9.5e-05
```

which is for a double-precision complex transform (looking at the first two letter of the `dcif` identifier) with `N=4` and `mflops=27.09`. The minimum average execution time that was measured was then:

```
5 * 4 * log2(4) / 27.09 = 1.4765 microseconds
```

Note that this is consistent with the 1.4765625e-06 execution time also shown in that entry.